# How to convert a 1 or 4 bit deep PNG into an 8-bit PNG image?

Tags: python-imaging-library

```
image = Image.open(file)   # file is 1-bit jpg
image = image.convert('P') # image become 8-bit 
colors = [0, 0, 0, 128, 0, 0, 0, 128, 0, 128, 128, 0, 0, 0, 128]
image.putpalette(colors)   # why use this code image become 4-bit ?
image.save("1.png",format='PNG') # save image become 4-bit png ????? (-w-)?
```

i need a 8-bit color png ,can you help me?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. If you have the world's first one-bit JPEG, please share it. Why do you need a palette with 5 RGB entries for a 1-bit image... two should be enough, surely?